# Why do my changes in ActionListener not take effect immediately?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, awt, actionlistener

This is my code:

```
public MyClass() {
    JButton btnNext;
    private void initComponents() {
        btnNext = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnNext.setText("Lanjut");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnNextActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        btnNext.setText("Loading...");
        callingFunction();
    }
}
```

**Note: callingFunction() is a function which takes a long time to execute.**

My problem is my button text will change to "Loading..." only after callingFunction() is done.

How do I change the btnNext text to "Loading..." immediately?

Comment: I think it was something like btnNext.revalidate(); although I'm not sure. But the best way is to do your function in a separate thread

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: @WhiteNightFury thanks, but this is not work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The button won't be repainted until control returns to the Swing event queue. Calling that function on the event dispatch thread is blocking the event queue.

As a workaround, tell it to run the function later (as soon as it's done repainting things):

In Java 8+:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> callingFunction());
```

In old Java:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        callingFunction();
    }
});
```

Note that this will still have the side-effect of blocking further interaction with the GUI while that function is running. If you want to run a long task in a background thread to keep the GUI interactive, use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). A minimal example, assuming `callingFunction` returns some result of type `String` (or whatever) that you want to use to update the display:

```
new SwingWorker<String,Void>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // called on a background thread
        return callingFunction();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // called on the event dispatch thread after the work is done
        String result;
        try {
            result = get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // do something with the result ...
        someTextField.setText(result);
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: in the SwingWorker how i call my current class ?, i.e when without the SwingWorker, i can using "this" in callingFunction()

Comment: @Tama Change `this.foo` to `ClassName.this.foo`.

Comment: in the last line i got this error
<i>incompatible types: void cannot be converted to SwingWorker</i>
what's wrong with me?

Comment: the code is too long, i used EventQueue, and its work. Thanks a lot